# with the microsoft identity foundation how long is default password token valid for?

Tags: asp.net-identity, wif, windows-identity

with Microsoft's identity foundation, you can reset the user's password and it generates a token.  This token is used to validate the password and is self-signed and contains an expiry period.

Does anyone know what the default expiry period is?

Answer (score 0):

The default security token lifetime is equal to **1 hour**. You can manage this parameter by [SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.DefaultTokenLifetime](http://SecurityTokenServiceConfiguration.DefaultTokenLifetime).
Please note one important moment. In point of fact the security token is valid whole lifetime + [clock skew delta](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.localservicesecuritysettings.maxclockskew(v=vs.110).aspx). You can set MaxClockSkew parameter by configuration STS by the same way.